# Compile ffmpeg with librtmp

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, openssl, rtmp

When compiling ffmpeg for OSX, I can simply use the:

```
./configure --enable-librtmp --enable-gpl
```

command and get a build that can I/O with an rtmp stream.

If I attempt to compile for iOS using:

```
./configure \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-mmx \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-shared \
--enable-librtmp \
--enable-avresample \
--enable-cross-compile \
--enable-pic \
--sysroot="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs /iPhoneOS6.1.sdk" \
--target-os=darwin \
--cc="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2" \
--extra-cflags="-arch armv7s -mfpu=neon -miphoneos-version-min=6.1" \
--extra-ldflags="-arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=6.1" \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=cortex-a9 \
--prefix=compiled/armv7s
```

it errors out saying `ERROR: librtmp cannot be found`. Specifically:

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -Wl,-dynamic,-search_paths_first -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -o /var/folders/4m/8hcrycqx777_ksz6d32nrn_m0000gp/T//ffconf.b2zp97z8 /var/folders/4m/8hcrycqx777_ksz6d32nrn_m0000gp/T//ffconf.VhdlpSe1.o -lrtmp -lz -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lbz2 -lz
ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/librtmp.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /usr/local/lib/librtmp.dylibignoring file /usr/local/lib/libz.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /usr/local/lib/libz.a

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_RTMP_Socket", referenced from:
      _check_RTMP_Socket in ffconf.VhdlpSe1.o
     (maybe you meant: _check_RTMP_Socket)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: librtmp not found
```

I have already compiled `openssl` for ios using `ios-openssl` found on github and `librtmp` through `rtmpdump`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up compiling `librtmp` and `openssl` using `ios-librtmp` and `ios-openssl`, installed `rtmpdump` and `openssl` using `brew`, `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, and then changing the files in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` for `libcrypto.pc`, `libssl.pc`, `openssl.pc`, and `librtmp.pc` to point to the iOS i386, armv7 & armv7s compiled libraries.